# Calling a function with a boolean return value inside of a trigger in postgres

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I am trying to call a function inside of a trigger in postgres. Basically I have a function,

```
c.check_level(bigint, integer)
```

which returns a boolean value.

I would like to call this function inside of a trigger as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION c.check_level_tg()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    parent_id  int8;
    level int;
    result bool;
begin
    parent_id := NEW.fk_parent;
    level := NEW.level;

    select * from c.check_category_level(parent_id, level) as result;

    if (result) then
        return (NEW);
    else 
        return(NULL);
    end if;

END; 
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION c.check_category_level_tg()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

When I try to put data in the table on which this trigger resides, I get an error:
"ERROR:  query has no destination for result data HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead. CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function".

The function c.check_level works properly when run in isolation.

Comment: `select c.check_category_level(parent_id, level) INTO result;`

Comment: Thanks! it works! Do you want to add it as an answer?

Comment: Maybe. BTW: I don't think it is a very good idea to hide the logic inside a function (function call overhead will be rather large) Besides, I expect the (recursive?) query inside the function to be related to the table for which the trigger is fired)

Comment: I have some complex data integrity rules which I need to apply to several tables. It is true that I hide the logic, but in return I only have to write the code once. I am not concerned about the speed because I will be doing far more reads on the tables than writes.

Comment: I understand you do not want to duplicate the code. And complex constraints sometimes require complex solutions. (in your case: limiting the nesting depth?) Have you considered using a canary-field (or table), maintained by a trigger function, but with a simple `CHECK` constraint on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
select * from c.check_category_level(parent_id, level) as result;
```

into:

```
SELECT c.check_category_level(parent_id, level) INTO result;
```